# Disable logging of Angular routing events

Tags: angular, logging

Is there a way to disable logging of events from `platform-browser.es5.js` in Angular 2/4? I want to be able to quickly read through my own logs and the Angular logs are drowning mine out.

[image: Angular router logging]

Comment: how did you enable them?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

By default, the routing events are not logged. So as Maximus suggested, you must have added code somewhere to turn them on. You just need to remove that code.

In my app, I turned on routing events here, in the app routing module:

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ], { enableTracing: true })
```

If you have code like this, either remove the `enableTracing` or set it to false.